# How to overwrite iris color pallates from theme to plugin

Tags: plugin-development, jquery, color-picker

I am working n plugin for `iris color pick` and in plugin I want to make my own color pallets and overwritten on iris color picker that use in theme.

I create 6 fields in plugin where user can put their color hex codes and when user save them, then they overwritten automatically on pallets on theme.

So I create a custom `iris color picker` for testing in theme. And I enter some color pallets hard codded and then I install my plugin and save color codes that should be overwritten on theme color pallets. But I have no idea how to do this. I search a lot but nothing get.

So lease guide me for this.

Answer (score 1):

You must make sure that your styles are hooked into the head of the site **after** other styles, so they will override them. You do this by putting them late in the action queue like this:

`add_action ('wp_head', 'your_output_function', 9999);`